# How to select file on fs with react and electron?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm building a desktop application with Electron and ReactJS.

I need to implement a feature to select a file from the file system, like how `input="file"` works in forms.  Actually, all I need is to obtain the absolute path of the file.

How can I achieve that?

I tried:

```html
<input type="file" onChange={function(e) {console.log(e.target.value)} } />
```

But it returns fake path due to security reasons.
I think dialogs in Electron may be useful for this purpose, but how can I propagate the file path to my react application then?

Comment: Could [this](https://discuss.atom.io/t/open-external-file-with-electron/18569/7) help you?

Comment: I need to get path of the file in user-friendly way.

Comment: Define 'user-friendly'

Comment: When you uploading some file on the web, file selection dialog appears. I need something like that, but with goal to obtain absolute path of selected file.

Comment: Have you tried using `showOpenDialog`?

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, it works! Problem I was stacked with is misunderstanding of how react is connected with electron.

Comment: No problem! The electron documentation is a great place!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;
```

...

```
document.querySelector('#fileSelect').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({
        properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']
    }, function (files) {
        if (files !== undefined) {
            // handle files
        }            
    })
});
```